# Why is the following Meteor/mongodb findOne returning undefined?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor, coffeescript

Code:

```
Template.chapterForm.rendered = ->
  Meteor.startup ->    
    currentChapter = Chapters.findOne(
      _id: "Wdyxj8pWg2HPzuDuf"
    )

    console.log currentChapter
    console.log currentChapter.content
```

I get the following output:

> undefined
>
> Exception from Tracker afterFlush
>   function: Cannot read property 'content' of undefined TypeError:
>
> Cannot read property 'content' of undefined

I'm puzzled. Is it a CoffeScript mistake or a Meteor/mongodb mistake?

(I tried moving the code to the top of the file. Still getting undefined)

**EDIT:**

Strange, if I do

```
Chapters.findOne({_id: "Wdyxj8pWg2HPzuDuf"});
```

In the console I do get the object:

```
Object
```

Comment: It happens because on the first page render the data didn't make its way to the client yet, so the collection is empty. Later the websocket connection gets the rest of the data and the call returns an object.

Comment: This is one of the most common gotchas in meteor programming. Please see [this post](https://dweldon.silvrback.com/guards) for a complete explanation and solutions.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Meteor findOne query returns undefined in one template helper. In other template helpers, same query works well](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17728386/meteor-findone-query-returns-undefined-in-one-template-helper-in-other-template)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. following two expression is totally same in coffeescript

   Chapters.findOne(
         _id: "Wdyxj8pWg2HPzuDuf"
   )

   Chapters.findOne({_id: "Wdyxj8pWg2HPzuDuf"})
2. I have no idea why you used 'Meteor.startup ->' in the template instance, it's not the good way. In the [Meteor docs](http://docs.meteor.com/#meteor_startup), "On a client, the function will run as soon as the DOM is ready." So the findOne action would be run right after the screen was created or rendered. I think it could ruin the Template instances life cycle order, so just use 'created' and 'rendered' cycle.
3. Additionally from #2, as of life cycle, you should have subscribed the collection before you fetched it (findOne), somewhere parents template or in the router code.

So the conclusion is it seems that there's no data in you browser mini-mongo.
That means you need to check in the browser console with 'Chapters.find().fetch()' command, and then if you can see the data on the console but have still the same error , you should check the life cycle to make the subscribe clearly.