# Meteor Mongo findOne returns undefined in method

Tags: mongodb, meteor

This method is called by a helper attached to a post. For some reason, even though the user is definitely in the collection, I get `TypeError: Cannot read property 'profile' of undefined` from the method when it gets called. What's the deal?

```
userImage: function(user) {
    var userObject = Meteor.users.findOne({ "username": user }, { profile: { image: 1 } });
    return userObject.profile.image;
}
```

Peripheral question, can I just call a method in a helper like this and have it return right through to the helper in the template?

```
userImage: function() {
    var user = this.username;

    Meteor.call('userImage', user, function(error,id) {
        if (error) {
            return console.log(error.reason);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Meteor findOne query returns undefined in one template helper. In other template helpers, same query works well](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17728386/meteor-findone-query-returns-undefined-in-one-template-helper-in-other-template)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you mean:

```
Meteor.users.findOne({username: user}, {fields: {'profile.image': 1}});
```

You should probably add a [guard](http://dweldon.silvrback.com/guards) after that like:

```
if(userObject && userObject.profile)
  return userObject.profile.image;
```

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28640400/get-meteor-method-return-value-inside-helper-function) for how to call a method from your helper.

Comment: I sorted out that Mongo syntax but userObject stays undefined. do you have any other ideas? Perhaps I'm going about this from the wrong angle. I'm really just trying to write a helper that will retrieve the user's profile.image to display in a post, but it seems Meteor.users won't let me access profile unless the user is logged in.

Comment: Just to clarify one point, when you say "the user is definitely in the collection" do you mean also that the user is definitely published to your client side collection?

Comment: Okay, so I've been way overcomplicating this. I've published the profile data and subscribed to it on the client. Now the whole lookup fits into a three-line helper: `var userObject = Meteor.users.findOne({username: this.username});` then `return userObject.profile.image;`.

Comment: Yes, that looks correct. Please make sure not to publish too much data about your users - see the "published secrets" section [here](http://dweldon.silvrback.com/common-mistakes).