# document.findOne() returns undefined

Tags: javascript, meteor, undefined, meteor-blaze, uc-browser

I am getting `undefined` when trying to query a collection, please what is wrong? When I ran it on the console it returns the same thing. In the Mongodb record, everything exist. I posted the screenshot using Robomongo.

```
userDetails: function () {
        if (!Meteor.user()) {
            Bert.alert("You are not logged in, permission denied.", "danger", "growl-top-right");
            return false;
        }else{
            return UserDetailsList.findOne({userId: Meteor.userId});
        }
    }
```

This is the blaze template:

```
<p>{{userDetails.industry}}</p>
<p>{{userDetails.profession}}</p>
```

[image: Robomongo screenshot to show record exists]

[image: UC Browser console]

Comment: Hello, may be this post is helpful to you. Check it out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28648980/meteor-mongo-findone-returns-undefined-in-method?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: Have you published / subscribed to the collection?

Comment: You also want to add `()` to `Meteor.userId` in your helper - as you have it in the console screenshot

Comment: Which version of Meteor are you using?

Comment: Are you able to provide the subscription/publication block for this template? or are you able to test it to see if it works with autopublish?

Comment: Yes. I have published and and subscribed. @Ankur Soni, I'm using version 1.2.1.  I have used the same code snippet on a project and it works, though the version is most recent 1.4.3. Could it be version issue because I experienced this when updating. with version 1.4.3, it not mandatory to map fields to their variable but in version 1.2.1 it's mandatory.

Comment: @kehinde have you added `()` to `Meteor.userId` yet?

Comment: Yes. I did added it.

Comment: Is your subscription `ready()` when you run `.findOne()`?

Comment: @ Michel Floyd, I think you've hit the nail on the head, how do I implement this?

Comment: @kehinde - It would help to also add code pertaining to pub/sub in your current question.

Comment: Thank you very much guys. You've really helped me. A mistake cost the man-hour seeking for a solution. It was because I copied and pasted code so I didn't edit it thoroughly, so what I published was not what I was querying.